# Scaling an image on a button which is resized

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, image-resizing

I'm working on an application which allows a used to place controls, move, resize, etc. But I'm trying to add icon images to a button control. When placed and instanced, it resizes the icon image per the code below.

But when I resize the control using user features and it calls this routing again, it fails to resize the image and it remains the original icon size. I've tried using "this.", passing the control to itself, I've done prints to ensure it's seeing the new size and width... what I am missing?

Also, when I create a 2nd control (or 3rd, etc), it uses the 1st image's initial size.
Thanks!

```
protected void sizeIcon () {
    try {
           File f2 = new File("media\\button.gif");
           BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(f2);
           BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), inputImage.getType());
           Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
           g.drawImage(inputImage, 7, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
           ImageIO.write(img, "gif", new File("test.gif"));
           this.setIcon(new ImageIcon("test.gif"));
           g.dispose();

        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got it, appears the old file was not being replaces.
-MH

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).